# Evaluate String expression in java

Tags: java, string, scriptengine

Given that I have the string below: `"june1 + august1"`.

I need the final value to evaluate to `"julyseptember"`

But the final value is currently evaluating to `"july + september"`.

What needs to be done so the string evaluates to what I need it to be?

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
value = "june1 + august1";
value = value.replaceAll("june1", "july");
value = value.replaceAll("august1", "september");
script = "print(msg)";
engine.put("msg", value);
engine.eval(script);
```

Comment: Consider the difference between your code here, and `String script = "print('july' + 'september')";`

Answer (score 3):

Bind the two variables `june1` and `august1` into the script context instead of injecting them with `replaceAll`:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

String script = "june1 + august1";

engine.put("june1", "july");
engine.put("august1", "september");

String result = (String) engine.eval(script);

System.out.println(result);  // will output julyseptember
```

Answer (score -2):

```
value = value.replaceAll(" + ", "");
```

Comment: the plus sign needs to be evaluated here. not replaced with "" to be concatenated.
 value = "1 + 2";
 retval = engine.eval(value);
 System.out.println(retval);

Comment: @Imran if you are going to criticize people’s answers then you should probably lay out your requirements in your question.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.